# Integrate my python code to Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am learning python (beginner) and I want to integrate a written code Tkinter.
The program consiste in receiving a verb by 'input' and send it to a function that checks the status of the verb and shows its conjugation.

What I want to do is:

- An 'Entry' to receive verb
- A 'Frame' to contain the result of the conjugation

I know only the basic functions of Tkinter and I think you could help me understand them.

(some text made by Google translation, I am french-speaker) Thank you in advance!

An example

```
def verification(verb):
    radical=verb[0:-2]
    subjects=["je","tu","il","nous","vous","ils"]
    termination=["e","es","e","ons","ez","ent"]
    for i in range(0,6):
        print(subjects[i],radical+termination[i])

verb = input("give a verb : ")
verification(verb)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a tutorial service.

Comment: first find tutorial.

Comment: Even in the Tkinter's documentation i don't see the part where they talk about this case :(  if you have a link for it please suggest me. Thanh you in advance

Comment: Look at the tkinter documentation abstractly, and you'll see that it calls regular python functions on button click, or whenever. You can call your function in any framework, doesn't need to be tkinter.

Comment: Okay sir, i Will try ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Without any consideration to styling/layout this can be done like this:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()                     
window.title("")

def verification():                 
    verb = verb_entry.get()
    radical=verb[0:-2]
    subjects=["je","tu","il","nous","vous","ils"]
    termination=["e","es","e","ons","ez","ent"]
    for i in range(len(conjugated_verbs)):
        conjugated_verbs[i].configure(text=subjects[i]+" "+radical+termination[i])
        conjugated_verbs[i].pack()

verb_entry = Entry(window)
verb_entry.pack()

button = Button(window,text="Conjugate",command=verification)
button.pack()

conjugated_verbs = []
for x in range(6):
    conjugated_verbs.append(Label(window))

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you sir, That's exactly what i wanted to do , Thank you again for your help ! Now i understand